# When i m Send Ajax Request in my web Application then controller side it give me script in request parameter in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

When I'm sending this ajax request:

```js
 $.ajax({
   url: "{{URL::to('admin/repcasetracker/getdiscount')}}",
   data: {
     serialnumber: serialnumberdata,
   },
   success: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
   }
 });
```

Controller:

```php
public function getdiscount(Request $request) {
  print_r("hi");
  dd($request->all());
}
```

Then it give me in controller side this type of response:

> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle =
>   doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|[]/\])/g, idRx =
>   /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <=
>   navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl',
>   addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb,
>   false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild ||
>   doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if
>   (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element,
>   eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function
>   (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;};
>   e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a,
>   recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className,
>   arrow, newClass; if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow =
>   '▼'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if
>   (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { arrow = '▶'; newClass
>   = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className =
>   s.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-(compact|expanded)\b/, newClass); if
>   (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0;
>   s < a.length; ++s) { if (-1 == a[s].className.indexOf(newClass)) {
>   a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML =
>   arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; function collapse(a,
>   recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if
>   (/\bsf-dump-expanded\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return
>   true; } return false; }; function expand(a, recursive) { var s =
>   a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className; if
>   (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(oldClass)) { toggle(a, recursive); return
>   true; } return false; }; function collapseAll(root) { var a =
>   root.querySelector('a.sf-dump-toggle'); if (a) { collapse(a, true);
>   expand(a); return true; } return false; } function reveal(node) { var
>   previous, parents = []; while ((node = node.parentNode || {}) &&
>   (previous = node.previousSibling) && 'A' === previous.tagName) {
>   parents.push(previous); } if (0 !== parents.length) {
>   parents.forEach(function (parent) { expand(parent); }); return true; }
>   return false; } function highlight(root, activeNode, nodes) {
>   resetHighlightedNodes(root); Array.from(nodes||[]).forEach(function
>   (node) { if (!/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/.test(node.className)) {
>   node.className = node.className + ' sf-dump-highlight'; } }); if
>   (!/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/.test(activeNode.className)) {
>   activeNode.className = activeNode.className + '
>   sf-dump-highlight-active'; } } function resetHighlightedNodes(root) {
>   Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str, .sf-dump-key,
>   .sf-dump-public, .sf-dump-protected,
>   .sf-dump-private')).forEach(function (strNode) { strNode.className =
>   strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight\b/, '');
>   strNode.className =
>   strNode.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-highlight-active\b/, ''); }); }
>   return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var
>   indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || '
>   ').replace(rxEsc, '\$1')+')+', 'm'), options =
>   {"maxDepth":1,"maxStringLength":160,"fileLinkFormat":false}, elt =
>   root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, s, h, t = [];
>   while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); for (i in x) { options[i] = x[i]; }
>   function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e) { if ('A' ==
>   e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' ==
>   e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } else if
>   (e.target.nextElementSibling && 'A' ==
>   e.target.nextElementSibling.tagName) { f(e.target.nextElementSibling,
>   e, true); } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey ||
>   e.metaKey; } function xpathString(str) { var parts =
>   str.match(/[^'"]+|['"]/g).map(function (part) { if ("'" == part) {
>   return '"\'"'; } if ('"' == part) { return "'\"'"; } return "'" + part
>   + "'"; }); return "concat(" + parts.join(",") + ", '')"; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' !=
>   refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover',
>   function (a, e, c) { if (c) { e.target.style.cursor = "pointer"; }
>   else if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML =
>   'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF
>   !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click',
>   function (a, e, c) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) {
>   e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r =
>   doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s =
>   r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode;
>   t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f =
>   f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t =
>   t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) {
>   r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc,
>   '\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if (/\bsf-dump-compact\b/.test(r.className))
>   { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (c) { } else if (doc.getSelection) {
>   try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) {
>   doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } else
>   if (/\bsf-dump-str-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault();
>   e = a.parentNode.parentNode; e.className =
>   e.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-str-(expand|collapse)\b/,
>   a.parentNode.className); } }); elt =
>   root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i <
>   len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt
>   = t[i]; if ('SAMP' == elt.tagName) { elt.className = 'sf-dump-expanded'; a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' !=
>   a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref';
>   elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; }
>   a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all
>   children'; a.innerHTML += '▼'; a.className += '
>   sf-dump-toggle'; x = 1; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { x
>   += elt.parentNode.getAttribute('data-depth')/1; } elt.setAttribute('data-depth', x); if (x > options.maxDepth) {
>   toggle(a); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-ref\b/.test(elt.className) && (a =
>   elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a;
>   if (/[[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a !=
>   elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { s = a.nextSibling;
>   elt.appendChild(a); s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s); if
>   (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += '
>   ▶'; } else { elt.innerHTML =
>   '▶'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className
>   += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '…'; elt.className =
>   'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } } if (doc.evaluate && Array.from &&
>   root.children.length > 1) { root.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
>   SearchState = function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; };
>   SearchState.prototype = { next: function () { if (this.isEmpty()) {
>   return this.current(); } this.idx = this.idx < (this.nodes.length - 1)
>   ? this.idx + 1 : this.idx; return this.current(); }, previous:
>   function () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return this.current(); } this.idx
>   = this.idx > 0 ? this.idx - 1 : this.idx; return this.current(); }, isEmpty: function () { return 0 === this.count(); }, current: function
>   () { if (this.isEmpty()) { return null; } return this.nodes[this.idx];
>   }, reset: function () { this.nodes = []; this.idx = 0; }, count:
>   function () { return this.nodes.length; }, }; function
>   showCurrent(state) { var currentNode = state.current(); if
>   (currentNode) { reveal(currentNode); highlight(root, currentNode,
>   state.nodes); } counter.textContent = (state.isEmpty() ? 0 : state.idx
>   + 1) + ' of ' + state.count(); } var search = doc.createElement('div'); search.className = 'sf-dump-search-wrapper
>   sf-dump-search-hidden'; search.innerHTML = '  0 of
>   0</span>    </svg> </button>    </svg> </button> '; root.insertBefore(search, root.firstChild); var state = new SearchState(); var searchInput =
>   search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-input'); var counter =
>   search.querySelector('.sf-dump-search-count'); var searchInputTimer =
>   0; var previousSearchQuery = ''; addEventListener(searchInput,
>   'keyup', function (e) { var searchQuery = e.target.value; /* Don't
>   perform anything if the pressed key didn't change the query */ if
>   (searchQuery === previousSearchQuery) { return; } previousSearchQuery
>   = searchQuery; clearTimeout(searchInputTimer); searchInputTimer = setTimeout(function () { state.reset(); collapseAll(root);
>   resetHighlightedNodes(root); if ('' === searchQuery) {
>   counter.textContent = '0 of 0'; return; } var xpathResult =
>   doc.evaluate('//pre[@id="' + root.id + '"]//span[@class="sf-dump-str"
>   or @class="sf-dump-key" or @class="sf-dump-public" or
>   @class="sf-dump-protected" or
>   @class="sf-dump-private"][contains(child::text(), ' +
>   xpathString(searchQuery) + ')]', document, null,
>   XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null); while (node =
>   xpathResult.iterateNext()) state.nodes.push(node); showCurrent(state);
>   }, 400); });
>   Array.from(search.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-search-input-next,
>   .sf-dump-search-input-previous')).forEach(function (btn) {
>   addEventListener(btn, 'click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); -1
>   !== e.target.className.indexOf('next') ? state.next() :
>   state.previous(); searchInput.focus(); collapseAll(root);
>   showCurrent(state); }) }); addEventListener(root, 'keydown', function
>   (e) { var isSearchActive =
>   !/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/.test(search.className); if ((114 ===
>   e.keyCode && !isSearchActive) || (isCtrlKey(e) && 70 === e.keyCode)) {
>   /* F3 or CMD/CTRL + F */ e.preventDefault(); search.className =
>   search.className.replace(/\bsf-dump-search-hidden\b/, '');
>   searchInput.focus(); } else if (isSearchActive) { if (27 ===
>   e.keyCode) { /* ESC key */ search.className += '
>   sf-dump-search-hidden'; e.preventDefault();
>   resetHighlightedNodes(root); searchInput.value = ''; } else if (
>   (isCtrlKey(e) && 71 === e.keyCode) /* CMD/CTRL + G */ || 13 ===
>   e.keyCode /* Enter */ || 114 === e.keyCode /* F3 */ ) {
>   e.preventDefault(); e.shiftKey ? state.previous() : state.next();
>   collapseAll(root); showCurrent(state); } } }); } if (0 >=
>   options.maxStringLength) { return; } try { elt =
>   root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str'); len = elt.length; i = 0; t =
>   []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i <
>   len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; s = elt.innerText || elt.textContent; x =
>   s.length - options.maxStringLength; if (0 < x) { h = elt.innerHTML;
>   elt[elt.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent'] = s.substring(0,
>   options.maxStringLength); elt.className += ' sf-dump-str-collapse';
>   elt.innerHTML = ''+h+'
>   ◀'+ ''+elt.innerHTML+'
>   ▶'; } } } catch (e) { } }; })(document);
>    pre.sf-dump { display: block; white-space: pre;
>   padding: 5px; } pre.sf-dump:after { content: ""; visibility: hidden;
>   display: block; height: 0; clear: both; } pre.sf-dump span { display:
>   inline; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact { display: none; } pre.sf-dump
>   abbr { text-decoration: none; border: none; cursor: help; }
>   pre.sf-dump a { text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; border: 0;
>   outline: none; color: inherit; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis {
>   display: inline-block; overflow: visible; text-overflow: ellipsis;
>   max-width: 5em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; vertical-align:
>   top; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis+.sf-dump-ellipsis { max-width:
>   none; } pre.sf-dump code { display:inline; padding:0; background:none;
>   } .sf-dump-str-collapse .sf-dump-str-collapse { display: none; }
>   .sf-dump-str-expand .sf-dump-str-expand { display: none; }
>   .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight,
>   .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight,
>   .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight, .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight,
>   .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight { background: rgba(111, 172, 204, 0.3);
>   border: 1px solid #7DA0B1; border-radius: 3px; }
>   .sf-dump-public.sf-dump-highlight-active,
>   .sf-dump-protected.sf-dump-highlight-active,
>   .sf-dump-private.sf-dump-highlight-active,
>   .sf-dump-str.sf-dump-highlight-active,
>   .sf-dump-key.sf-dump-highlight-active { background: rgba(253, 175, 0,
>   0.4); border: 1px solid #ffa500; border-radius: 3px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-hidden { display: none; } pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-search-wrapper { float: right; font-size: 0; white-space:
>   nowrap; max-width: 100%; text-align: right; } pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-search-wrapper > * { vertical-align: top; box-sizing:
>   border-box; height: 21px; font-weight: normal; border-radius: 0;
>   background: #FFF; color: #757575; border: 1px solid #BBB; }
>   pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > input.sf-dump-search-input {
>   padding: 3px; height: 21px; font-size: 12px; border-right: none;
>   width: 140px; border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-bottom-left-radius:
>   3px; color: #000; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper >
>   .sf-dump-search-input-next, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper >
>   .sf-dump-search-input-previous { background: #F2F2F2; outline: none;
>   border-left: none; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; } pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next {
>   border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; }
>   pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper > .sf-dump-search-input-next >
>   svg, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper >
>   .sf-dump-search-input-previous > svg { pointer-events: none; width:
>   12px; height: 12px; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-search-wrapper >
>   .sf-dump-search-count { display: inline-block; padding: 0 5px; margin:
>   0; border-left: none; line-height: 21px; font-size: 12px;
>   }pre.sf-dump, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-default{background-color:#fff;
>   color:#222; line-height:1.2em; font-weight:normal; font:12px Monaco,
>   Consolas, monospace; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;
>   position:relative; z-index:100000}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-num{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-const{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-str{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-cchr{color:#222}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-note{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-ref{color:#a0a0a0}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-public{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-protected{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-private{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-meta{color:#b729d9}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-key{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump
>   .sf-dump-index{color:#a71d5d}array:1 [  "serialnumber" => "ASDQ13"]Sfdump("sf-dump-2124159715")

Answer (score 4):

You need to use

```
return $request->all();
```

instead of

```
dd($request->all());
```

in your controller function.
`return $request->all();` just return the response with your `$request` data.

Hope this helps you!